# How can I use googletest in openwrt?

Tags: c++, arm, googletest, openwrt

I have an application that I am building for an arm linux machine with openwrt.  I have multiple packages (A, B, C) where C is dependent on A and B, and C is the one I most need to write tests for.  I have been unable to figure out how to cross compile googletest.

Is it suggested that I create a another package (D) with my tests and pull in A, B, and C?

Or can I link to googletest from inside C and build my tests as part of that package?

Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can build googletest on your target machine and test your C package in a classic way. If you don't want to do this for some reason (e.g. target machine very slow), you can still compile and run the project on your local x64 PC, but you need to somehow abstract-out and mock the parts that are ARM target specific.

Comment: @pptaszni Are suggesting to build the testing binary on the target machine?

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it, if it is difficult to abstract ARM-specific code. Or if you actually can do this, then even better - separate ARM specific code and then you can test it anywhere.